# Is it possible to change clients TFS port without recreating workspace?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs

I want to change the TFS Ports of my TFS clients without re-creating the workspace. Is that possible?

Reason: I'm using a NAT on TFS server gateway and my network admin changed the router, which uses - and blocks - the port 8080, which I was using.

If so, how is that possible?

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 pointed to TFS 2010.

Answer (score 2):

You can change the port in IIS like you would any website.

Comment: And your workspace should stay intact (since the internal TFS Server ID will be the same).

Comment: @Mike Cheel I didn't get the point. Have you realized that I want to change the port of the CLIENTS (not the server port)?

Comment: If you change server port to different port your clients then connect on that port.